# Require no funciona en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Buenas tengo un programa muy particular en **node.js**. Resulta que me lanza una excepción cuando hago un `require` de una libreria o de una función.

Os pongo pequeños fragmentos del código:

1. El archivo **inject.js** llama a **WAPI.js** mediante:

```js
WAPI.waitNewMessages(false, async (data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ...
```

Si hago un `require`: por ejemplo:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

2. **WAPI.JS** la instancia en wapi.js es de la función:

```js
window.WAPI.waitNewMessages = function (rmCallbackAfterUse = true, done) {
    window.WAPI._newMessagesCallbacks.push({ 
        callback: done, 
        rmAfterUse: rmCallbackAfterUse 
    });
    return true;
};
```

En el momento que hago un `require` falla la ejecución del programa y no encuentro la forma de solucionarlo.

Haciendo un debugging, me lanza este error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module

Gracias.

Comment: estas ejecutando tu programa(script) en el navegador o en node?

Comment: La ejecución la hago con node, pero se abre  crhome para Whatsapp Web. Si te refieres a los logs los visualizo desde la terminal de VCode.

Comment: que error te da puedes poner el log

Comment: Me da este error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module

Comment: estas usando algun bundler como webpack o parcel?